# Исключить товары со скидкой woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет.
Есть такой скрипт. Он выводит скидку в корзине.
Как можно сделать, чтобы товарам, у которых акционная цена не выводилась скидка?

```
function woo_discount_total(WC_Cart $cart) {

        if(is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        
            return;

        }

        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        $products_total = 0;
        
        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $product_price = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], 'woo_second_price', true );
            $products_total += $product_price * $cart_item['quantity'];
        }   
            
        if($products_total >= 47.5 && $products_total <= 94) {
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.2; // 0.03 - это 3%
            $cart->add_fee('На Ваш заказ действует скидка 20%', -$discount);
        } elseif($products_total >= 95 && $products_total <= 189) {
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.3; // 0.05 - это 5%
            $cart->add_fee('На Ваш заказ действует скидка 30%', -$discount);
        } elseif($products_total >= 190) {
            $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.4; // 0.05 - это 5%
            $cart->add_fee('На Ваш заказ действует скидка 40%', -$discount);
        }
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'woo_discount_total');
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Подниму........

Comment: Вопрос: Как реализуется скидка? Это вторая цена или купонная??? В зависимости от этого надо по разному писать (проверять). Опять же проверка должна ли быть проверка даты окончания скидки или количества?

Comment: Скидка реализуется на всю итоговую цену в корзину. У каждого товара есть произвольное поле "woo_second_price" (виртуальная цена).
То есть просто в корзине идет цикл перебирания всех товаров в корзине и потом идет проверка на общее количество этой виртуальной цены у всех товаров в корзине (if($products_total >= 47.5 && $products_total <= 94)).
Сейчас надо сделать, если в корзине есть товар с базовой скидкой woocommerce, то чтобы он не входил в цикл перебора товаров и к нему не применялась скидка.

Comment: Например в корзине 4 товара, у каждого товара виртуальная цена по 15 CV. Получается общее 60, условие срабатывает и присваивается скидка в корзине на итоговую цену. Если без товара со скидкой все работает. НО, если добавится товар со скидкой, он тоже входит в эту схему, а нужно, чтобы такие товары исключались.

Comment: Тебе надо $cart_item (если это не товар) превратить в товар и запросить, есть ли у него скидка  product->is_on_sale(). Если есть скидка то и исключаешь из расчёта